# How do I configure Eclipse's Subversion config file to use my private-key?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, ssh, config

I'm using Eclipse and the Subversive for SVN control, in Windows. I've also installed TortoiseSVN. The SVN repository I'm using is utilizing a svn+ssh scheme, and there is no way to change that.

Now, there's a file in %APPDATA%\Subversion\config that I need to edit to perform SVN interaction in Eclipse without typing in the password every time. The line in this config file reads now (default):

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no
```

I've read a bit on the web that the $SVN_SSH is an environmental variable in Windows, and in this case it points to TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe, which is correct.

What is the additional parameteres to append this config to make it take my private key? I've updated the "authorized_keys" file on the server (in my .ssh folder) with my public keyphrase, and I've tested and confirmed that logging in to the SVN server outside Eclipse works like it should with my private/public key pair.

The problem here is to make it all work inside Eclipse, and it's quite frankly a small nightmare :/ If anyone has experienced the same, or knows any remedy, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Try Pageant http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the 'SVN_SSH' environment variable the rest of the line is ignored, so you should either replace '$SVN_SSH ssh' with the path to the program, or move the required arguments to the end of the SVN_SSH environment variable.